# I can't get the coefficients of the taxa that contribute to the groups differences

Tags: coefficients, phyloseq

I'm trying to get the coefficients of the taxa that generate the most differences between the groups in my permutest of types of supplies for the animals.
I paste the results of the permutest:

permutest(betadispersionAlimentación, pairwise = TRUE)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwuZY.png)

When I try to get the coefficients, Studio answer me with this:

coefficients(betadispersionAlimentación)["C",]
NULL

The object to get the coefficients is the type of:
Permanova?
Betadisper?
Permutest?

i don't know how can I get the taxa (genus, Family, Specie...) that contribute to the differences.

can anybody help me, please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody who have the same problem.
From the day that I posted the question I have worked about that.
To get de genus or the specie that more contribute to the dissimilarity I used the vegan library.

Here I used the Vegan Distance to create de distance object

```
DIST_ABUNDANCES <- vegdist(t(OTU_ABUNDANCES))
```

Here I took the anova function to create all the values.

```
anova(betadisper(DIST_ABUNDANCES, META_ABUNDANDES$Sexo))
```

Here I made the permutest to compare all the values of the variable Sexo

```
permutest(betadisper(DIST_ABUNDANCES, META_ABUNDANDES$Sexo), pairwise = TRUE)
```

Here I took the correlation coefficients of the anova to seek the objetive

```
COEF_ABUNDANCES <- coefficients(PERMANOVA_ABUNDANCES)["Sexo1",]
```

I created the top coeficients object

```
TOP.COEF_ABUNDANCES <- COEF_ABUNDANCES[rev(order(abs(COEF_ABUNDANCES)))[1:20]]
```

Here I designed the plot of the coefficients

```
par(mar = c(3, 14, 2, 1))
barplot(sort(TOP.COEF_ABUNDANCES), horiz = T, las = 1, main = "Top taxa")
```

I followed this tutorial: https://mibwurrepo.github.io/Microbial-bioinformatics-introductory-course-Material-2018/multivariate-comparisons-of-microbial-community-composition.html

Comment: Also, to establish the parameters of the plot you can access to this information. In my case,  I had to set a bigger size to the left   side parameter of the plot. http://rfunction.com/archives/1302